# How to check if a list of base type contains at least one instance of some child types

Tags: c#

I have a list of base class like this:

```
List<BaseClass> ChildClasses
```

I have child classes like this:

```
class ChildFoo : BaseClass {}
class ChildBar : BaseClass {}
class ChildBaz : BaseClass {}
class ChildQax : BaseClass {}
class ChildBox : BaseClass {}
...
```

I need to implement a method which can query the `ChildClasses` list to see if it has all of the types I pass to it, which are all derived from `BaseClass`.

So, if I call this method for types `ChildFoo` and `ChildBar`, it should return true if `ChildClasses` list contains at least one instance of `ChildFoo` and `ChildBar`.

How can I approach this situation?

Comment: Something like this: `bool result = ChildClasses.All(item => item != null && item is ChildFoo);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it should return true if ChildClasses list contains at least one instance of ChildFoo and ChildBar.

You could use [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) with [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx). You could then combine the expression multiple times.

```
var containsFooAndBar = ChildClasses.OfType<ChildFoo>().Any() 
                     && ChildClasses.OfType<ChildBar>().Any();
```

---

#### Alternate

You could also approach it from the other direction. Create a list of all mandatory types that need to be included and then execute a query on that list using the `ChildClasses` list as the input. This is just a different way of writing the above, the `ChildClasses` collection is still iterated over 2x.

```
Type[] mandatoryTypes = new Type[] {typeof(ChildFoo), typeof(ChildBar)};
var containsFooAndBar = mandatoryTypes.All(mandatoryType => ChildClasses.Any(instance => instance != null && mandatoryType == instance.GetType()));
```

Comment: Is there a way to constrain the elements of `mandatoryTypes` to children of `BaseClass`? So only the types that derive from `BaseClass` can be added there.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin - not directly. You would have to create a wrapper or a method that added the types where you could constrain the input.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the inheritance hierarchy doesn't go any deeper than in your example...

Create a hashset of the actual types in the list:

```
var actualTypes= new HashSet<Type>(ChildClasses.Select(x=>x.GetType()));
```

Then create a hashset of the required types:

```
var requiredTypes = new HashSet<Type>
        {
            typeof(ChildFoo),
            typeof(ChildBar)
        };
```

Remove all the actual types from the set of required types:

```
requiredTypes.ExceptWith(actualTypes);
```

If `requiredTypes.Count == 0` then the list contained all the required types. If `requiredTypes.Count > 0` then there were missing types and these will be left as the contents of `requiredTypes`.

This approach should be easier to implement if the number of required types is variable (let the caller pass in a hashset directly or an IEnumerable from which you construct the hashset) and be performant for large numbers of items in either ChildClasses or required types.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method which takes your list of classes, and also an array of types, and then check to see if the provided list contains all of those types:

```
    static bool ContainsTypes(List<BaseClass> list, params Type[] types)
    {
        return types.All(type => list.Any(x => x != null && type == x.GetType()));
    }
```

And implement it like this:

```
    List<BaseClass> baseClasses = new List<BaseClass>();
    baseClasses.Add(new ChildFoo());
    baseClasses.Add(new ChildBar());
    //Population code here...
    var result = ContainsTypes(baseClasses, typeof(ChildFoo), typeof(ChildBar));
```

---

**Or if you want to use extension methods**

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool ContainsTypes(this List<BaseClass> list, params Type[] types)
    {
        return types.All(type => list.Any(x => x != null && type == x.GetType()));
    }
}
```

And once again, implement like so:

```
List<BaseClass> baseClasses = new List<BaseClass>();
baseClasses.Add(new ChildFoo());
baseClasses.Add(new ChildBar());
//Population code here...
var result = baseClasses.ContainsTypes(typeof(ChildFoo), typeof(ChildBar));
```